# WooCommerce single product slider

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

Do you guys know a setting or another WooCommerce hook for this WooCommerce single product slider hook(https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_single_product_flexslider_enabled) that will only enable in desktop view and disables in mobile(768px breakpoint) view.

Hook will disable in mobile but enabled in desktop view (https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_single_product_photoswipe_options).

Comment: Moderators at strike https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an - so I also will not do **any** (further) content/curation-related action here

Comment: HI bud, thats not how PHP works, its a server sided language that doesn't do anything after the page has been loaded, only when the page is loaded php will  execute. just rewrite your code so it works on mobile and desktop. Also the formatting of this page is poorly done, and you shouldn't use the answer feature to add extra information to your question, you should edit the post instead.